# ServiceStack - injecting Properties

Tags: servicestack, inversion-of-control

I am getting very confused with the Funq container.

I have the following:

```
public interface IConnectionString
{
     string ConnectionString { get; set; }

}

public class FoundationConnection : IConnectionString
{
    public FoundationConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my AppHost, I would like to register

```
   container.Register<IConnectionString>(c=> new FoundationConnection(AppSettings.Get(
                        "FoundationConnectionString", "").MapHostAbsolutePath()));
```

In my ServiceInterface I want to call this injected method somehow:

```
 public class ServiceInterface : Service
 {
  public IConnectionString foundationConnection { get; set; }

     public object Any(SomeRequest request)
     {

         string injectedProperty = foundationConnection.ConnectionString;
      }
  }
}
```

Issue is that foundationConnection is null and never injected.

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use `AppSettings` to access config settings which would allow you to source configuration from a [number of different and cascading configuration sources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AppSettings).

But I've tested this using these types:

```
public interface IConnectionString
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}

class FoundationConnectionString : IConnectionString
{
    public FoundationConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

and it's working correctly after registering it in the AppHost.Configure():

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IConnectionString>(c => 
        new FoundationConnectionString("My Connection"));
}
```

and accessing it from a test service:

```
[Route("/test")]
public class Test : IReturn<string> { }

public class TestService : Service
{
    public IConnectionString Config { get; set; }

    public object Any(Test request)
    {
        return Config.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Which returns "My Connection" when called.